# Elements moving when resizing or zooming browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There is a lot of examples about this, but none of them have worked for me. I have a couple of tables in my webpage, which are inside a `<div>` (which I am using as a background, because it doesn't cover the whole screen), but whenever the window is resized or zoomed in/out, everything gets on top of everything else and it is a whole mess.

My goal: I would like it to look like Stack Overflow where no matter what you resize or how you zoom in or out everything stays put, nothing moves. This is what my background and tables look like:

```
#bluebackground {
    background-color: #a4ceff;
    height: 50%;
    width: 90%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 5%;
}

.table1 {
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-family: 'Lato', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 3px solid white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 90%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 5%;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 100px;
    font-size: 80%;
}
```

Comment: Could you add an example http://jsfiddle.net. It's very hard to visualise your problem without seeing a working example with all your code.

Comment: This is more or less what kind of look likes but I have more tables with input elements in it: http://jsfiddle.net/Y6bcZ/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should stop using % to define your width and height, because what %width/height mean is changes width/height according to the parent element. If your parent element is the window , than whenever you change the window size, element inside change size as well. Instead , give a fixed size to your element

```
#bluebackground {
background-color: #a4ceff;
height: 500px;  //change all the % to actual pixel 
width: 500px;
position: absolute;
top: 200px   //change all the % to actual pixel 
left: 20px;
}

.table1 { // and all these, however you can choose to stay % on table
width: 200px;
top: 100px;
left: 20px;
font-size: 14px; 
}
```

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/Y6bcZ/ , you can try moving the display window up and down, the div won't change size

As for how many pixel for each element, you have to figure them out yourself.
I left the table with % because the parent div(bluebackground) is now fixed size, so the table won't change size